# Best way to add method to all eloquent models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `last()` method on one of my models.

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function last()
    {
        return Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    }
}
```

I want the same method on my other models. What the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this one in two ways.

---

With an abstract class that you extend in all your other models instead of `Model`.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public static function last() {
        return static::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()
    }
}
```

so you will have the following

```
class Article extends BaseModel
{

}
```

---

Or more appropriately, as you pointed out, with a trait

```
trait Lastable {

    public static function last()
    {
        return static::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    } 

}
```

That you use in the desired classes.

```
class Article extends Model {
    use Lastable;
}
```

Comment: `$this::` should be `static::`.

Comment: May I create trait instead of abstract class? It will be the same? One of my model extends class from vendor package, so that model cannot be extended.

Comment: Yes, the same principle applies and would be a more suited solution.